# What is an assignment with a class name and arguments called in Scala syntax?

Tags: scala

i saw some code snippets like below:

```
val future = testActor ? Running()
val Success(running: Boolean) = future.value.get
```

So `future` is of type `Future`, what makes me confusing is the way it assign value to variable `running`.

Can anyone explain to me what is this `val Success(running: Boolean)` called in scala?

Thanks

Comment: It’s called Extractor: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html Other languages have it too, which are sometimes also called Destructure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a form of [**pattern matching**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html), or in this case also called [**extractors**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).

So the same way you can do something like:

```
val tuple = (1, 2) 
opt match {
  case (x, y) => ???
}
```

You can do this:

```
val tuple = (1, 2) 
val (x, y) = tuple
```

---

Anyways, it is worth to mention in this answer, that piece of code is a complete code smell.

For four reasons:

1. That extractor is not exhaustive. If the future failed with some exception the result of `future.value.get` would be a **Failure(e)** containing the exception, which in this case won't be caught or handled, and will be suppressed with a `MatchError` losing all the information of what went wrong.
2. Code that uses futures for something, must use it for everything. You should compose futures using `map` & `flatMap`, so all your program is a big future. Awaiting or trying to get the value of the future means that the future was misused or that the coder doesn't know how to use futures.
3. `Future.value` is mostly useless, it tries to give you the value of the future if it already completed. Which again, goings against the way futures should be used.
4. `Option.get` is a bad practice, for reasons similar to the first point.

In general, that line is assuming the future is already complete and that completed without errors. Both assumptions are unrealistic on real code.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Pattern Matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). You can assert that a value is of the specified subtype, and immediately get access to its structure. For example:

```
val one = Some("hello")
val two = None
val Some(hello) = one  // hello is "hello"
val Some(wrong) = two  // error
```

Sometimes this technique is also called destructuring.

See also [Extractor Objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).